# python change variable class without instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a Python beginner, currently working on a Tic-Tac-Toe game using classes. Actually, I'm using classes on purpose in order to get some practice, even though it would make sense to avoid using them.

Here's part of the code:

```
import sys


class Build_board():
    boardg = []
    num_of_rows = 3
    num_of_cols = 3
    def generate(self):
        for x in range(self.num_of_rows):
            self.boardg.append(['0' for x in range(self.num_of_cols)])

    def print_board(self):
        for row in self.boardg:
            print(" ".join(row))

class Players(object):
    name = ""
    score = 0
    players_dic = {}
    def ask_name(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.name = input("What's {plyr} player's name? ".format(plyr="first" if i == 0 else "second"))
            self.players_dic["p" + str(i+1) + "_name"] = self.name
            self.players_dic["p" + str(i+1) + "_score"] = self.score


class Players_turn(Players): #PROBLEM HERE

    def __init__(self, turn):
        self.turn = turn

    def whos_turn(self):
        if self.turn % 2 == 1:
            return self.players_dic['p1_name'], '1'
        elif self.turn % 2 == 0:
            return self.players_dic['p2_name'], '2'
        else:
            return 'incorrect', '3'
```

The above Players'turn() class is intended to return the the player that is supposed to have his turn based on the which turn it is right now.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    turn = 0
```

Turn variable created here.

```
    board = Build_board()
    board.generate()

    players = Players()
    players.ask_name()
    pdic = players.players_dic

    players_turn = Players_turn(turn)
    who_now = players_turn.whos_turn()


    def game():
        for round in range(3):
            while True:
                global turn 
                turn += 1 
                players_turn = Players_turn(turn) 
                print("Turn", turn)
                if ['0' in list_ for list_ in board.boardg]:
                    print("It's", players_turn.whos_turn()[0] + "'s turn.") 
                else:
                    return False
        sys.exit()

game()
```

In the game() function I redefine variable turn and increase it by 1 every turn, then create an instance of the Players_turn() class in order to change the value of turn variable so that the 'whos_turn()' within a class can return a different player. 
I know there are better ways of doing it without using a global variable.

My question is: 
Is there any other way I can change the variable value in an instance of a class / class, without creating/overwriting it with a new instance of the same class?

Comment: Not really addressing your question, but... your abstraction can use some improvement. Representing an action (a turn, building a board) using an object instead of a method is problematic. The data owned by `Players_turn` is data that should be owned by a game class. If you're trying to practice/apply OOP, start with sensible abstractions first. It will make problems like the one you're having easier to solve.

Comment: `Player_turn` is not a proper object...